# Spring LDAP Basic Auth caching some clients but not others

Tags: spring-security, postman, soapui, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am using a `org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.LdapAuthenticationProvider(LdapAuthenticator authenticator, LdapAuthoritiesPopulator authoritiesPopulator)` to validate my clients.  When I am calling from SoapUI I can see this pointcut being executed every time `execution(Authentication org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(Authentication))`  When I call from postman, it only gets executed the first time postman calls.

It appears that somehow my app is caching the client and saying it does not need re-authenticated when I call from postman, but this is not happening when I call from soapui.  What is the difference?

I have tried changing all settings I can see in postman and soapui, but I cannot seems to make any difference in the results.  Can someone describe, or point me to a resource that describes what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be related to cookies... In postman I found a property, disable cookie jar.  If that is enabled i get the same performance as soapui and it always validates.  I guess now I need to see how cookies work with spring security.